# Validating cell no using regular expression

Tags: html, validation

I am trying to validate cell no using html. I've write the following regular expression but its not working. Can anybody please help me?

```
<input required="required" name="txtcellno" id="txtcellno"  type="text" value="" pattern="/^+[9][2][0-9]{1,10}$/" placeholder="+92xxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a lack of effort.

Answer (score 1):

`+` has special meaning, and should be escaped (`\+`).

Input patterns must match the whole string, so `^` and `$` are unnecessary.

Input patterns must not be wrapped in `/`...`/`

Given all that, and simplifying `[9][2]` to `92`:

```
<input required="required" name="txtcellno" id="txtcellno"  type="text" 
   value="" 
   pattern="\+92[0-9]{1,10}" 
   placeholder="+92xxxxxxxxxx" />
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/jELiI

Comment: Minor: `\d` is a standard shortcut for digits.

Comment: True. I was trying to leave things in a somewhat-recognizable state. :-)

Comment: No worries there, the added hard returns inside the tag help a lot. For that alone I'd have up-voted.